# "geforben" as punchline

Tags: german-to-english, joke

Here is an "amusing" story about someone struggling with the German language. I can see the mistake, but I feel like I'm missing an extra angle on the joke. Is there some additional pun or something that I can't find?

> Engel stand mit der deutschen Sprache stets auf dem Kriegsfuße, und viele amüsante Geschichtchen werden ihm nacherzählt. Das bekannteste wird auf einen Besuch des alten Kaisers Wilhelm bei Kroll zurückgeführt, der bei dieser Gelegenheit in guter Laune zu Engel sagte: “Na, Engel, wir müssen doch beide eigentlich gleichaltrig sein, aber Sie haben immer noch so schöne schwarze Haare!”, worauf Engel schmunzelnd flüsterte: “Majestät, das ist alles *geforben*!” Das war jahrzehntelang ein geflügeltes Wort in Berlin.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's nothing more to the punchline than the fact that people struggling with irregular verbs is funny - someone saying "geforben" instead of "gefärbt" is funny in the same way that saying  "I've brung it" rather than "brought" is funny.

Comment: Right. Though "färben" is actually a regular verb (`färben, färbte, gefärbt`) and Engel inflects it *as if* it were irregular (in analogy with `werden, wurde/ward, geworden`).

Comment: Thanks, good to have confirmed - just seemed rather mean-spirited if that were the case!